# Loop over the properties of member variable for conditional check in MVEL

Tags: java, mvel

Member variable categories must have MAIN type and url.

**Stream**

```
boolean mainCatImage=categories.stream()
   .anyMatch(categories -> categories.getType()
   .equals("MAIN") && StringUtils.isNotBlank(categories.getUrl()));
```

I have rewritten the same usign MVEL. The below works, but is there any way to do it in other way with less code in MVEL?

**MVEL**

```
mainCatImage = false;
foreach (cat : input.categories) {
   if(cat.type == 'MAIN' && cat.url!=empty){
        mainCatImage = true;
    }
}
    mainCatImage;
```